# ADD failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder805243059/tmp/ during Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Getting the following error when i issue the trigger the docker build.

```
ADD failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder805243059/tmp/app-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The context location :

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 ri-server ri-server 4096 Oct 30 09:04 ./

drwxrwxr-x 30 ri-server ri-server 4096 Oct 18 10:20 ../

-rw-r--r--  1 ri-server ri-server 1438 Oct 30 09:01 Dockerfile

-rw-rw-r--  1 ri-server ri-server   42 Aug 30 10:12 .dockerignore

drwxrwxr-x  2 ri-server ri-server 4096 Oct 30 07:12 target/

drwxrwxr-x  2 ri-server ri-server 4096 Oct 30 09:00 tmp/
```

The jar is present inside both target/ and tmp/ directories shown above

Dockerfile :

```
FROM < private image>
ADD tmp/app.jar app.jar
ADD certificate/keystore /keystore

ADD prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar /jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar
ADD prometheus/inca.yml /prometheus-inca.yml

ENTRYPOINT java $JVM_OPTS \
-DCASSANDRA_HOST=$CASSANDRA_HOST \
-DCASSANDRA_PORT=$CASSANDRA_PORT \
-DCASSANDRA_USER=$CASSANDRA_USER \
-DCASSANDRA_PASSWORD=$CASSANDRA_PASSWORD \
-DORTHO_TOPIC=$ORTHO_TOPIC \
-DORTHO_APP_ID=$ORTHO_APP_ID \
-DHTTP_PORT=$HTTP_PORT \
-DHTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=$HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS \
-DHTTPS_PORT=$HTTPS_PORT \
-DHTTPS_BIND_ADDRESS=$HTTPS_BIND_ADDRESS \
-DCERTIFICATE_KEYSTORE_PATH=$CERTIFICATE_KEYSTORE_PATH \   
-DLOG_LEVEL=DEBUG \
-jar app.jar
```

Any idea why am i getting the error?

Comment: show your copy command.

Comment: ADD tmp/app-jar-with-dependencies.jar app.jar

Comment: I have also tried giving absolute path of the jar that begins with a '/', but its always takes /var/snap/docker directory. Not sure how do i overide this directory,

Comment: I use Dockerfile.

Comment: please, share the dockerfile

Comment: is it being ignored in .dockerignore?

Comment: No its not ignored. The content of .dockerignore is : *
!obj/Docker/publish/*
!obj/Docker/empty

Comment: okay try with `COPY tmp/app.jar /app/app.jar`

Comment: Still same error, after COPY command. Had tried it earlier.

Comment: how you start the build process , with whcih command ?

Comment: docker build -t <private image>:v1.0 .

Comment: remove .dockerignore for a while and then try to build.

Comment: this may help https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/90

Comment: Thanks @Adiii. This got resolved with removing the .dockerignore file. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved with deleting .dockerignore file. Although this did not contain any visible culprits but that did help after removing. This issue needs to be resolved from docker team definitely.
Thanks @Adiii who helped me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Renamed .dockerignore file and that worked for me.